# XPATH Pull First and Last name from multiple root element

Tags: xpath, power-automate

Getting a pull from a Saas API that sends unformatted XML. Need to pull the first and last names out of each element to send to another application.

I haev tried numerous things in Power Automate but they all error out due to the XML not having a parent node.

```
<Request ID="19131795" Status="Approved">
  <TimeOffDate>2023-02-14</TimeOffDate>
  <TimeOffDayOfWeek>Tuesday</TimeOffDayOfWeek>
  <TimeStart></TimeStart>
  <TimeEnd></TimeEnd>
  <TimeOffHours>8.000</TimeOffHours>
  <TimeOffTypeName>Maternity Leave</TimeOffTypeName>
  <EmployeeID>646028926148N</EmployeeID>
  <LoginID>Marie</LoginID>
  <Firstname>Marie-Eve</Firstname>
  <Lastname>B</Lastname>
  <UserCategory>Software Development</UserCategory>
  <SubmittedDate>2022-03-11</SubmittedDate>
  <Deducted>Yes</Deducted>
  <Comment>time-off request created by administrator</Comment>
</Request>
<Request ID="21301056" Status="Approved">
  <TimeOffDate>2023-02-14</TimeOffDate>
  <TimeOffDayOfWeek>Tuesday</TimeOffDayOfWeek>
  <TimeStart>2023-02-14T13:00:00</TimeStart>
  <TimeEnd>2023-02-14T17:00:00</TimeEnd>
  <TimeOffHours>4.000</TimeOffHours>
  <TimeOffTypeName>Paid Time Off - Salary</TimeOffTypeName>
  <EmployeeID>FRM992097</EmployeeID>
  <LoginID>Robert</LoginID>
  <Firstname>Bobby</Firstname>
  <Lastname>D</Lastname>
  <UserCategory>Information Technology</UserCategory>
  <SubmittedDate>2023-01-06</SubmittedDate>
  <Deducted>Yes</Deducted>
  <Comment></Comment>
</Request>
<Request ID="21324804" Status="Approved">
  <TimeOffDate>2023-02-14</TimeOffDate>
  <TimeOffDayOfWeek>Tuesday</TimeOffDayOfWeek>
  <TimeStart></TimeStart>
  <TimeEnd></TimeEnd>
  <TimeOffHours>8.000</TimeOffHours>
  <TimeOffTypeName>NL Parental Leave 1</TimeOffTypeName>
  <EmployeeID></EmployeeID>
  <LoginID>Kamila</LoginID>
  <Firstname>Kamila</Firstname>
  <Lastname>K</Lastname>
  <UserCategory>NL Customer Service</UserCategory>
  <SubmittedDate>2023-01-09</SubmittedDate>
  <Deducted>Yes</Deducted>
  <Comment>time-off request created by administrator</Comment>
</Request>
```

I have tried the following xpath filters.

'*/Firstname|*/Lastname')
'Firstname|Lastname')

Comment: It's XML not well-formed due to missing root element. Should like `<parent><Request>....</parent>`

Comment: Can you please revise your XML and update it accordingly?

Comment: Can you also show what output you expect?  It's VERY important in the context of your question and is important given you're asking about a solution in PowerAutomate.

Comment: Also can you check and revise the formatting of the XPath expressions you've tried, please? It's important to format them using code blocks, just as with the XML, They don't look well-formed, to me; but maybe that's a copy-and-paste error.